# shell script - Remove character before a specific pattern

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, cut

I've my `/etc/hosts` :

```
#192.168.54.144  name1
#192.168.54.144   name2
192.168.54.143   name3
```

I would like to remove all character `#` which is followed by an ip address Ipv4 to obtain that :

```
192.168.54.144  name1
192.168.54.144   name2
192.168.54.143   name3
```

I guess I should use `sed` or `awk` or `cut` ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do full matching of an IPv4 address, or would it be enough with testing if the `#` was followed by a digit? Do you have lines starting with `#` that should not be processed?

Comment: I would prefer to match with a full ipv4 because some comments in the file could start with a digit and shoudn't be uncommented :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

Only matching real IP ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928879)):

```
sed -E 's/^#(((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))/\1/' file
```

or simple matching which checks for digit after `#`:

```
sed 's/^#\([[:digit:]]\)/\1/' file
```

This will just print the result, add `-i` to edit file in place.

---

You might also use `perl` with lookehead to not need a backreference:

```
perl -pe 's/^\#(?=[[:digit:]])//' file
```

Comment: which sed is that? I'd have expected a -r instead of -E

Comment: hm, probably true ... seems not working with `--posix`, but then also not with `-r`, added "GNU". So maybe someone can write a non-GNU answer ;-)

Comment: my GNU sed (2.4.1) doesn't understand -E

Comment: --> `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: I've sed 4.2.2 so it's works for me, what does `-E` option ? It's for regular expression? I can't see that on the man page :) 
Thanks

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options

Comment: For GNU, it's a recently added synonym for -r @Couim it makes it compatible with BSDs' sed, and POSIX

Comment: @Grump thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
sed  "/^#[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]\{3\}/s/#//g" filename
```

output

```
sed  "/^#[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]\{3\}/s/#//g" filename
192.168.54.144  name1
192.168.54.144   name2
192.168.54.143   name3
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using python and it worked fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
g=re.compile(r'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')
m=open('u.txt','r')
for i in m:
    if re.search(g,i):
        print i.strip().replace("#","")
```

output
1

```
92.168.54.144  name1
192.168.54.144   name2
192.168.54.143   name3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat myfile | tr -d '#'
```

Simple with tr!